# Tqdm auto switch between notebook and terminal

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I am using tqdm (from tqdm.auto import tqdm) in notebook and output is nice and correct but when that same line is used while running script in the terminal I get clogged multiline output. Is there any way for tqdm to differentiate between notebook and terminal outputs?

Answer (score 11):

You should try using

```py
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
```